# Python: Derivative of trig functions

Tags: python

I am trying to identify what the problem with the differentiation of trig functions in Python. I use scipy.misc.derivative.

Correct case:

```
def f(x):
    return math.sin(x)
y=derivative(f,5.0,dx=1e-9)
print(y)
```

> This will give a math.cos(5) right?

My problem is here. Since python accepts radians, we need to correct what is inside the sin function. I use math.radians.

If I code it again:

```
def f(x):
    return math.sin(math.radians(x))
y=derivative(f,5.0,dx=1e-9)
print(y)
```

This will give an answer not equal to what I intended which should be math.cos(math.radians(5)).

Am i missing something?

Comment: please fix the indentation of your code. Simply paste it in, select it and then hit `Ctrl+K`

Comment: probably you are missing the chain rule of derivatives

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be consistent with the argument of the trigonometric function. Is not that *"Python accepts radians"*, all programming languages I know use radians by default (including Python).

If you want to get the derivative of 5 degrees, yes, first convert to radians and then use it as the argument of the trigonometric function. Obviously, when you do

```
y=derivative(f,5.0,dx=1e-9)
```

using

```
def f(x):
    return math.sin(x)
```

you get `f'(x)=cos(x)` evaluated at `5` (radians). If you want to check that the result is correct this is the function to check, not `f'(x)=cos(math.radians(x))`, which will give you another result.

If you want to pass 5 degrees, yes, you will need to get the radians first:

```
y=derivative(f,math.radians(5.0),dx=1e-9)
```

which will be the same as `cos(math.radians(5))`.

Here is a working example

```
from scipy.misc import derivative
import math

def f(x):
  return math.sin(x)

def dfdx(x):
  return math.cos(x)

y1 = derivative(f,5.0,dx=1e-9)
y2 = dfdx(5)
print(y1) # 0.28366
print(y2) # 0.28366
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! I have another problem though:

If my function is let's say f(x) = sin(e^x) and I need to get the derivative of that,

My code would be: